# How do I type object keys as members of an array?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects coming from an API, like this:

```
const items = [
    {
        title: 'foo',
        date: '123'
    },
    {
        title: 'bar',
        date: '456'
    }
]
```

I would like to use all the available item titles to type the key for another object. For example:

```
const titles = items.map(item => item.title)
type titlesType = typeof items[number]

type fizz = {[titlesType] : boolean}
```

My current approach is impossible in TS.

Has anybody had this issue before, or have any suggestions?

Much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it, you just need to add the `['title']` index:

```
type TitlesType = typeof items[number]['title']
```

However, to get the type `"foo" | "bar"`, you also need to declare `items` as const, otherwise `TitlesType` type will be just `string`:

```
const items = [
    {
        title: 'foo',
        date: '123'
    },
    {
        title: 'bar',
        date: '456'
    }
] as const // <----------- 
type TitlesType = typeof items[number]['title']
const foo: TitlesType = 'foo' // no error
const fooz: TitlesType = 'fooz' // error
```